# Getting lift-scalate to accept .jade files

Tags: lift, sbt, pug, scalate

I am currently re-implementing some project using Lift. All the old views were done using `jade` for `express.js`, and I was glad to read that Scalate seems to be able to handle it as well.

It's not as easy as it sounds, it seems. After adding the line

```
(new ScalateView).register
```

and changing the view files, it should work, according to any source I found. But when I try to open the `http://localhost:8080/`, I get an error "The Requested URL / was not found on this server".

The console logs tell me they were searching the files `index.ssp` and `index.scaml`. But there is, of course, only an `index.jade`. I thought it could be that the version of `scalate` was too old, so I changed my `build.sbt`:

```
name := "project"

version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.9.1"

seq(webSettings: _*)

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val liftVersion = "2.4-M5"
  Seq(
    "net.liftweb" %% "lift-webkit" % liftVersion % "compile->default",
    "net.liftweb" %% "lift-mongodb" % liftVersion % "compile->default",
    "net.liftweb" %% "lift-mongodb-record" % liftVersion % "compile->default",
    "net.liftweb" %% "lift-wizard" % liftVersion % "compile->default",
    "net.liftweb" %% "lift-scalate" % liftVersion % "compile->default",
    "org.fusesource.scalate" % "scalate-core" % "1.5.3" % "compile->default"
  )
}

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.5" % "test->default",
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.0.4.v20111024" % "container",
  "javax.servlet" % "servlet-api" % "2.5" % "provided->default",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "0.9.26" % "compile->default"
)
```

But it's still the same problem.

What is the undocumented magic trick to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the Lift Scalate plugin doesn't support .jade files by default

I had to create my own ScalateView.scala and LiftTemplateEngine.scala and add them to my project tree in src/main/scala/code/lib/

Moreover there is a bug somewhere between scalate and Lift wich make it fail with scala 2.9.0+. I had to use scala 2.8.0 to get it work

The two files :

http://pastebin.com/mLU0DAFu

http://pastebin.com/AmJmBjE7

Be sure to import code.lib.ScalateView in your Boot.scala file